# Web service xml select attributes get

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I am having the data in the XML file, but I want to draw data from XML and web services have specific names like using a question such as:

```
name | surname | phone  | 
------------------------|
john | bravo   | 03 291 | 
ali  | life    | 2314   |
```

I want to be that way, but elemlist []. Attributes [fieldname] .Value (); I'm having trouble parts

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("../" + Directory + FileName + ".xml"));

List<String> tablo = new List<string>();
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Data");
string[, ] ic = new string[AlanAdi.Count, elemList.Count];
foreach(string alan in AlanAdi) {
    ic = elemList[ ? ? ].Attributes[AttrNames].Value();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample xml? It's kind of hard to figure it out from your code.

Comment: example.xml
-------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Veriler>
<Veri name="john" surname="bravo" phone="03 291" />
.....
</Veriler>

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming `AlanAdi` is some sort of a class that has indices for the table columns in the order `[Name, Surname, Phone]` you should do this:

Create a class to extract data from your xml:

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static string GetName(this XElement element)
    {
        return element.Attribute("name").Value;
    }

    public static string GetSurname(this Xelement element)
    {
        return element.Attribute("surname").Value;
    }

    // Another method for phone here
}
```

Now you can iterate the elements and produce the result:

```
for(int i=0; i<elemList.Length; i++)
{
    ic[i,0]=elemList[i].GetName();
    ic[i,1]=elemList[i].GetSurname();
    ic[i,2]=elemlist[i].GetPhone();
}
```